# On click event seemingly not over the whole element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following code in a `D3` project:

```
function addSquare() {

  //Create SVG element
  var SQsvg = d3.select("#square")
    .append("svg")
    .attr({
      "width": 70, 
      "height": 20, 
      id: "squaresArea"
    })
    .on("click", resetRefresh);


  SQsvg.append("text")
    .text("Refresh")
    .attr({
      x: 15, //margin.left,
      y: 15,
      "font-family": "sans-serif",
      "font-size": "14px",
      "text-decoration": "underline",
      fill: "blue"
    })
    .on("click", resetRefresh);

  function resetRefresh() {
    console.log("hello")
      //update bar chart when user selects a square
    dsPieChart(initialMeasure, pieDataCSV);
    TOPbarChartUpdate("N", initialMeasure, "lightgrey",false);
  }

}
```

When I move my cursor to the text Refresh the interactivity does not seem to span the whole word - why is this? and how do I amend the above so that all the text will trigger the event?

A live example of the whole project is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/w9lBwZhoHqQbmNUjihQv?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its due to the container the pie chart is in is ontop of the Refresh button. I have appended the Refresh button to the body, and seemed to solve the problem :

```
 d3.select('body').append('svg').append("text")
    .text("Refresh")
    .attr({
      x: 15, //margin.left,
      y: 15,
      "font-family": "sans-serif",
      "font-size": "14px",
      "text-decoration": "underline",
      fill: "blue"
    })
    .on("click", resetRefresh);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/rc78OaAZbOVPjPznGKok?p=preview

Comment: This was just to work out what the problem was. I would change the order in which you append the pie chart and refresh button to the SVG.

Comment: ok - currently the Refresh button is in a seperate div - maybe need to move it into the top right corner of the div used by the pie?

Comment: depends whether you want it to be in SVG. I recommend just using a plain HTML button for it, that'l be the easiest way.